# Nested for..of iterate over first array Element

Tags: javascript, iterator, for-in-loop

I have Data Structure like this

```
const array = [
  [["first_name" , "First"], ["image" , "image"]],
  [["email" , "email"]],
  [["last_name","last_name"]],
  [["password" , "password"], ["password", "password"]]
]
```

My Iterator Implementation is

```
let arr = array.values();
let obj = {
  [Symbol.iterator]: function () {
    return {
      next() {
        for (const iterator of arr) {
          for (let [, value] of iterator) {
            return {
              done: false,
              value,
            };
          }
        }

        return {
          done: true,
        };
      },
    };
  },
}
```

But when I iterate it `[...obj]`

I am getting Only first element of 2D array

The output I am getting is `["First" , "email" , "last_name" , "password"]`

Expected output `["First" , "image" , "email" , "last_name" , "password", "password"]`

Nested for..in iterate only 1st element of nested array

**Note:- Above solution is working fine with Symbol.Iterator generator function**

Comment: My guess is that first return exists that inner `for` loop iteration and the goes to next outer iteration. Why not just use iterator with generator `[Symbol.iterator]: function*()` ?

Comment: Like I already mentioned.. It is working fine with yield.... I just want to implement in that way..I have also read somewhere that nested for..in is error prone

Answer (score 0):

Like Nenad Vracar's answer, since it is returned from the inner for loop statement, it does not loop all the inner arrays, only the outer array loops and ends.

Individual states must be able to be saved to implement what you want with `Symbol.iterator` alone without using `Generator`.

```js
const array = [
  [["first_name" , "First"], ["image" , "image"]],
  [["email" , "email"]],
  [["last_name","last_name"]],
  [["password" , "password"], ["password", "password"]]
];

const obj = {
  [Symbol.iterator]: () => {
    return {
      stack: [...array],
      target: [],
      next() {
        if (!this.target.length && !this.stack.length) return {
          done: true,
          value: undefined,
        }
        if (!this.target.length) this.target = this.stack.shift();

        return {
          done: false,
          value: this.target.shift()[1],
        };
      },
    }
  }
};

console.log([...obj]); // ['First', 'image', 'email', 'last_name', 'password', 'password']
```